# Selecting components of vectors in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensor

I have a tensor with shape (7, 2, 3)
I want to select one of the two row vectors from each of the 7 2x3 matrices, i.e.

```py
[
 [[0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1]],

 [[0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1]],
 ...x7
]
```

to

```py
a = [
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]
 ...x7
]
b = [
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1]
 ...x7
]
```

each with shape (7, 3).

How can I do this without `reshape`? (I find `reshape` to be kind of confusing when some dimensions are the same).

I also know of

```py
np.array(map(lambda item: item[0], x)))
```

but I would like a more concise way if there is one.

Comment: just use looped indexing: `data[:, i, :]` where `i` loops from 0 through 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use looped indexing: `data[:, i, :]` where `i` loops from 0 through 1

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
 [[0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1]],

 [[0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1]]
])
print(a[:, 1, :])
```

will produce

```bash
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. perfect, thanks!

Comment: kindly accept if this answers your question

Comment: need to wait 3 more minutes ^^ you were too fast